# Match members of a tuple to members of a list, python

Tags: python, tuples

I thought this would be fairly trivial but it's turned out be more difficult than I'd anticipated.

I have a list of tuples:

```
  tuples = [('apples', 2, 'apple'), ('oranges', 3, 'orange')]
```

I have list of lines containing a possible member of the tuple in the list of tuples:

```
 list_of_lines = ['banana 1234', 'apple 5678', 'oranges 4321','apples 8765', 'orange 1111')]
```

For tuple[0] and tuple[2] in tuples, I need to match to the member in first position in list_of_lines and get that member's value (in second position).  The key thing is output these results on one line. For the first tuple in tuples, for example, the desired output would be:

```
 'apples', 8765, 2, 'apple',5678
```

i.e. the original members of the tuple, now with values matched from list_of_lines.

If we try to do this with

```
  for tup in tuples:
    for line in list_of_lines:
        if tuple[0] == line.split()[0]:
            print tuple[0], line.split()[1]
        if tuple[2] == line.split()[0]:
            print tuple[2], line.split()[1]
```

then nothing is on one line and we get repeated matches.

Comment: Your list_of_lines contains no definition for "orange".  Will there be one in the real problem, or do you want nothing to be printed in that case?

Comment: I would use a dictionary where your fruit is your key and your values are the number that you want.

Comment: @DSM sorry, just made the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than scanning `list_of_lines` every time you need to locate an entry, it's easier to pre-process the list into a dictionary:

```
tuples = [('apples', 2, 'apple'), ('oranges', 3, 'orange')]
list_of_lines = list_of_lines = ['banana 1234', 'apple 5678', 'oranges 4321','apples 8765', 'orange 1111']
d = dict(l.split() for l in list_of_lines)
for t in tuples:
    print "'%s', %s, %s, '%s', %s" % (t[0], d[t[0]], t[1], t[2], d[t[2]])
```

This prints out:

```
'apples', 8765, 2, 'apple', 5678
'oranges', 4321, 3, 'orange', 1111
```

Comment: what about KeyError 'orange'?

Comment: @Max Li: There are actually no missing values in list_of_lines. I edited the OP to reflect this. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @aix: This is great. It hadn't even occurred to me that dictionary lookup could be done that way.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier if you convert your `list_of_lines` to a dict first.

```
>>> tuples = [('apples', 2, 'apple'), ('oranges', 3, 'orange')]
>>> list_of_lines = ['banana 1234', 'apple 5678', 
...                  'oranges 4321','apples 8765']
>>> line_no = dict(x.split() for x in list_of_lines)
>>> result = [(x[0], line_no.get(x[0], None), x[1], 
               x[2], line_no.get(x[2], None)) for x in tuples]
>>> result
[('apples', '8765', 2, 'apple', '5678'), ('oranges', '4321', 3, 'orange', None)]
```

Comment: did you try your code actually? errors both in syntax and results. "result=[('oranges', '4321', 3, 'orange', None)]"

Comment: @MaxLi Yes, I did try the code. I copied `tuples` and `list_of_lines` from OP. Seems like he had an extra bracket that I removed now. But the rest of the code does work. And the result does include `apples` etc. What do you mean errors in result?

Comment: @MaxLi Ah I see what you mean. But not my mistake. OP had edited the post and added `orange, 1111` *after* I answered. But based on my input as shown above, the answer is correct, and so is the logic.

Comment: hm, sorry, result is and was ok, I must have applied it on altered "list_of_lines" input

Answer (score 0):

Try an existence check on the variables and an after-the-fact print statement to ensure that they're on the same line.

```
tuples = [('apples', 2, 'apple'), ('oranges', 3, 'orange')]
list_of_lines = ['banana 1234', 'apple 5678', 'oranges 4321','apples 8765']
for tup in tuples:
    first = False
    second = False
    for line in list_of_lines:
        if tup[0] == line.split(' ')[0]:
            first = tup[0] , line.split()[1]
        if tup[2] == line.split(' ')[0]:
            second = tup[2] , line.split()[1]
        if first and second:
            print first + second
```

Output is:
`('apples', '8765', 'apple', '5678')`

Not quite sure if I understood the question, but I hope this got you in the right direction.

Comment: please read the question: output must be: ('apples', 8765, 2, 'apple',5678) and not ('apples', '8765', 'apple', '5678')

Answer (score 0):

I'll give this a shot:

```
for tup in tuples:
    matches = []
    for line in list_of_lines:    
        if tup[0] == line.split()[0]:
            matches.append([tup[0], str(line.split()[1]), str(tup[1])])
        if tup[2] == line.split()[0]:
            matches.append([tup[2], str(line.split()[1])])
    if len(matches) > 0:
        matches = [", ".join(x) for x in matches]
        print ", ".join(matches)
```

Output is:

```
apple, 5678, apples, 8765, 2
oranges, 4321, 3
```